# AMS-style vs amsart table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, amsart

According to the [AMS Style Guide](https://www.ams.org/publications/authors/AMS-StyleGuide-online.pdf), the table of contents should include only numbered section heads. Here is a screenshot from page 19:
[image]

However, when using the `amsart` document class, the command `\tableofcontents` does not behave as required by AMS (please see the minimal working example below).

My question is, what is the best way to achieve an AMS-styled table of contents?

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section*{An unnumbered section}
\section{A section}
\subsection{A subsection}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `amsart` does quite a lot of work to force unnumbered section heads to go in the table of contents and the guide you cite indeed has unnumbered chapters in the table of contents: each part has an introduction, which is realized as an unnumbered chapter.

So I interpret the statement as “numbered heads below the section level don't go in the table of contents”.

On the other hand, the `amsart` class sets `tocdepth` to 2, whereas `amsbook` sets it to 1.

Add `\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}` to your document preamble.